# Kong setup with Cassandra 2.2.7

Tags: cassandra, kong

Just getting started with using [Kong](https://getkong.org/) but I've been facing this issue.

I'm trying to setup Kong on a Mac and following the instructions from here:

[Kong for Mac](https://getkong.org/install/osx/)

I already have Cassandra 2.2.7 installed and running locally. I can connect to it through 'cqlsh' and create a keyspace etc.

But kong does not start when I run the following command:

```
kong start
```

I've tried the --vv option and it gives me the following output:

```
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [verbose] no config file found at /etc/kong.conf
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [verbose] no config file found at /etc/kong/kong.conf
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [verbose] no config file, skipping loading
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] admin_listen = "0.0.0.0:8001"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] anonymous_reports = true
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_consistency = "ONE"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_contact_points = {"127.0.0.1"}
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_data_centers = {"dc1:2","dc2:3"}
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_keyspace = "kong"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_port = 9042
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_repl_factor = 1
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_repl_strategy = "SimpleStrategy"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_ssl = false
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_ssl_verify = false
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_timeout = 5000
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cassandra_username = "kong"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cluster_listen = "0.0.0.0:7946"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cluster_listen_rpc = "127.0.0.1:7373"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cluster_profile = "wan"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] cluster_ttl_on_failure = 3600
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] custom_plugins = {}
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] database = "postgres"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] dnsmasq = true
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] dnsmasq_port = 8053
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] log_level = "notice"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] lua_code_cache = "on"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] lua_package_cpath = ""
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] lua_package_path = "?/init.lua;./kong/?.lua"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] lua_ssl_verify_depth = 1
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] mem_cache_size = "128m"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] nginx_daemon = "on"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] nginx_optimizations = true
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] nginx_worker_processes = "auto"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] pg_database = "kong"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] pg_host = "127.0.0.1"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] pg_port = 5432
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] pg_ssl = false
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] pg_ssl_verify = false
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] pg_user = "kong"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] prefix = "/usr/local/kong/"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] proxy_listen = "0.0.0.0:8000"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] proxy_listen_ssl = "0.0.0.0:8443"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] serf_path = "serf"
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [debug] ssl = true
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [verbose] prefix in use: /usr/local/kong
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [verbose] running datastore migrations
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [verbose] could not start Kong, stopping services
2016/09/19 11:13:30 [verbose] leaving serf cluster
```

I don't see any logs locally that tell me what exactly is the issue. I've looked on the web a fair bit but haven't found a solution.

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Comment: Never mind! I was using Kong 0.9.1 which by default it seems uses Postgres. I had to add a line to the conf file which fixed the issue: database = cassandra

Answer (score 2):

Try with `KONG_DATABASE=cassandra kong start` to make it explicit that Kong should use Cassandra.

Or update the `database` property in the configuration file to `cassandra`.

On a side note Kong >= 0.9.2 has more descriptive errors.